# How to get only user-defined globals in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm (sort of) familiar with `globals()` in Python (We're talking 2.7.9 here). My problem is that the dictionary returned contains all globally available variables, like `__file__`, `__doc__`, objects of imported modules, etc.

Is there any way of getting a list or dict containing only those variables I defined globally? I mean something like this:

```
>>> a = 6
>>> b = 42
>>> foo = "bar"
>>> my_globals()
{'a': 6, 'b': 42, 'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY question - seems that you're solving the wrong problem here. Why do you want global variables at all, and why do you need to get them dynamically?

Comment: Why do you want that? What is your actual problem?

Comment: For logging purposes it would be convenient to dump out all variables i have defined.

Comment: Another idea: use a single global dict container for your values. This way you'll be able log track it and log with confidence.

Comment: so there's no built-in way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1. Get a list with all globals
2. Remove all the values with `__something__`. A simple regex will do the trick here.
3. You have user-defined globals.

Comment: Sounds good, although there are objects of imported modules too and who knows what else I didn't stumble upon.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't be 100% sure in all cases with this approach.